# Square every number in an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, if we run 5678 through the function, 25364964 will come out. So I wrote a code like this.

```
number = 5678

for ch in str(number):
    print (int(ch)**2, end="")
```

And got the correct output.

```
25364964
```

However, if I put this code under a function, the expected result isn't showing up.

```
def square_every_number(number):
    for ch in str(number):
        return ((int(ch)**2))


print(square_every_number(5678))
```

Output:

```
25
```

I'm getting only the square for the first digit.

Comment: `return()` terminates the function immediately.  You're only going through the loop once.

Comment: What do you think `return` does?

Comment: Your function is exiting on the first iteration of the for loop, thus returning 5*5.

Answer (score 6):

You are returning on the first loop. You should build up your result and return that.

```
def square_every_number(number):
    res = ''
    for ch in str(number):
        res = res + str(int(ch)**2)
    return res
```

Or a shorter function:

```
def square_every_number(number):
    return ''.join(str(int(ch)**2) for ch in str(number))
```

Comment: @DanD. edited the short version to use tuple expansion instead of list expansion. Smart move!

Answer (score 0):

You were returning after squaring the first character, please try squaring every character and form  the resultant number in your function and return the final result as below.

```
def sq_every_num(number):
    result = ''
    for ch in str(number):
        result += str(int(ch) ** 2)    
    return int(result)
```

output:

```
result = sq_every_num(5678)
print result, type(result)
25364964 < type 'int'>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid there still appears to be unformatted code and there's no expansion of why OP's code didn't work.